# Sencha Architect "Unable to open your app.json file"

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I've been trying to follow [Sencha's basic tutorial on Sencha Architect](https://docs.sencha.com/architect/4.2/guides/tutorials/first_desktop_application.html) with the Sencha Architect trial version, but I've been stuck on the step of the tutorial titled, "[Save Your Project](https://docs.sencha.com/architect/4.2/guides/tutorials/first_desktop_application.html#tutorials-_-first_desktop_application_-_save_your_project)". I've been encountering this error in the Sencha Architect Logs every time I save my new projects:

[image: Sencha Architect Screenshot]

As the error suggests, there was no "app.json" generated by Sencha Architect:

[image]

The "CMD Output Tab" also produces this output upon saving the Sencha Architect project:

```
[INF] Initializing empty workspace at C:\Users\marco\source\sencha-sandbox\Test2
[INF] Copying framework to C:\Users\marco\source\sencha-sandbox\Test2\ext
[INF] Added framework ext to workspace.json
[ERR] The specified string cannot be converted into a valid namespace identifier
Exception in thread "Thread-13"
com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: com.sencha.exceptions.ExState: Invalid namespace : Test2
at com.sencha.tools.server.service.tasks.DispatchTask.execute(DispatchTask.java:55)
....
```

If it makes any difference, I am using the latest versions of Java JDK (17.0.1) and Ruby (3.0.2p107).

Here is a selection of some of the things I've tried to resolve the issue, none of which have worked:

- Restart windows ❌
- Recreate project ❌
- Create new project with Ext JS 6.0.x, instead of the latest version ❌
- Reinstall everything and try following the tutorial again on a
  completely new instance of Windows 10 ❌

What I have been able to do successfully is create and run a project through the Sencha CMD following the Sencha CMD tutorial, so I find it interesting that the Sencha CMD-generated project works perfectly fine, yet my Sencha Architect Trial version cannot create a functioning project.

Comment: Try to use completely different folder path. It's possible that there are  some worksapces or something in your folder `sencha-sandbox`.

Comment: @pagep Trying `C:\sencha\NewProject`, the same error is reproduced.

Comment: I would than check the version of CMD. I no longer work with ExtJS/Architect but I would make sure  that it's using the right version. It's also possible that you have too new version of Sencha CMD and Architect doesn't know how to work with it correctly or it has the old version and doesn't work with it.

Comment: @pagep I am using the latest versions of Architect and CMD, having installed both together last week.

Comment: I would contact Sencha support. It looks like bug in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got into contact with one of Sencha's engineers today, who helped me to resolve this:

When Sencha Architect (v4.2.9) installed with CMD, the CMD version (v7.3.0.19) that was automatically installed alongside Sencha Architect was causing this error.

To fix this version issue, within Sencha Architect, I had to go to menu at Edit > Preferences > Dependencies, and change the default "Custom Cmd Base Path" from

```
C:\Users\marco\bin\Sencha\Architect\Cmd
```

to the install location of the standalone Sencha CMD

```
C:\Users\marco\bin\Sencha\Cmd
```

After doing that, you re-launch Sencha Architect, and Sencha Architect will ask you to update Sencha CMD, which you proceed with. From there, it seems that all your future projects should be good to go without issue.